# Disable Dovecot pipe error message

Tags: email, cpanel, dovecot

I have a server running Dovecot (VPS managed by cPanel).

I have it set to pipe all email to a certain address into a program that I wrote. The problem is that if there is an error, that is if it exits with a status other than 0, it replies to the sender with a nasty error message (including the path to the program).

I would love for those messages to go to me instead, but at the very least, disabled so that the senders never see them.